# Wifi and bluetooth issue on HP laptop

Tags: networking, wireless

I have a Hp laptop on which I've installed Ubuntu 16.04. My wifi is not working. I already install drivers from **Additional Drivers**. Ethernet is working fine.

This is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
    02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Kernel modules: wl
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: The device is not supported.

Comment: Is that mean I can't use Ubuntu ?

Comment: It will be supported. When, we don't know. That doesn't mean you can't use Ubuntu, even if you must have WiFi any cheap USB dongle will do. Quite a *non sequitur* there.

Comment: and Bluetooth ?